# Insert json data onto sql, keys not same in all the dictionary and some of the keys is not exists

Tags: python, mysql, json, dictionary, sql-insert

I'm still not able to insert mydata to sql. I have search but fail to find the solution. I read json file and insert the data onto sql db. The json file contain list of multiple dictionary of key/value. Below is the parameters column configured 
for the db table1

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| log_number                | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp                 | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| staff_id                  | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| staff_name                | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| temp_staff_id             | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| temp_staff_name           | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| staff_department          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_id                | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_number            | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state                     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city                      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description               | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| additional_remarks        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Not all dictionary have all the db parameters listed. Some doesn't have 'state' and 'city' and some dictionary doesn't have 'additional_remarks'..some have 'temp_staff_id' and 'temp_staff_name'. Overall the parameters in the db will cover different type of key/value data of the json file that need to be inserted.

Below is the sample data that need to be inserted to the db table1

```
{
  "response": {
   "client_log": {
      "data": [
          {
          "log_number": "1",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-11 04:23:31",
          "staff_id": "A123",
          "staff_name": "Krill",
          "staff_department": "Sales",
          "service_id": "11111",
          "service_number": "BU-11111",
          "description": "This is description1"
         },
         {
          "log_number": "2",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-11 07:03:39",
          "staff_id": "A456",
          "staff_name": "James",
          "staff_department": "Graphic",
          "service_id": "22222",
          "service_number": "XU-22211",
          "State": "AAA",
          "City": "AAA"
         },
         {
          "log_number": "3",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-27 14:29:11",
          "temp_staff_id": "A571",
          "temp_staff_name": "Mary",
          "staff_department": "Engr",
          "service_id": "89000",
          "service_number": "SP-89001",
          "State": "BBB",
          "City": "BBB"
         },
         {
          "log_number": "4",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-27 15:08:20",
          "staff_id": "A765",
          "staff_name": "Alex",
          "staff_department": "Sales",
          "service_id": "09880",
          "service_number": "XU-09880",
          "description": "This is description3333"
         }
      ],
      "query": "4"
    },
  }
}
```

I'm using the script below to insert the data...I insert all the keys available in the table1.. but I got error

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
   mydata = json.load(f)

#Insert the values onto table1 of db.
sql = "INSERT INTO `table1` (`log_number`, `timestamp`, `staff_id`, `staff_name`, `temp_staff_id`, `temp_staff_name`, `staff_department`, `service_id`, `service_number`, `state`, `city`, `description`, `additional_remarks`) VALUES ( %(log_number)s, %(timestamp)s, %(staff_id)s, %(staff_name)s, %(temp_staff_id)s, %(temp_staff_name)s, %(staff_department)s, %(service_id)s, %(service_number)s, %(state)s, %(city)s, %(description)s, %(additional_remarks)s )"
cursor.executemany( sql, mydata['response']['client_log']['data'])
```

Error...

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%(temp_staff_id)s, %(temp_staff_name)s, 'Sales', '11111', 'BU-11111', %(state)s,' at line 1
```

If all the key of each dictionary same and exists and follow exactly like parameters of the db I can insert data without any error.

As the set of dictionary keys in the json file is not same and some not exists...so, how can I do the data insertion..for example if no state or city or additional_remarks just insert null. I'm not sure how to do it when some of the key parameters is not same with others or not exist. I hope you guys can help and advise me the solution. Thank you

---

---

I have tried mr rashid solution and return error below

```
<class 'dict'> ====> mydata is a dictionary type
{'response': {'client_log': {'data': [{'log_number': '1', 'timestamp': '2020-01-11 04:23:31', 'staff_id': 'A123', 'staff_name': 'Krill', 'staff_department': 'Sales', 'service_id': '11111', 'service_number': 'BU-11111', 'description': 'This is description1'}, {'log_number': '2', 'timestamp': '2020-01-11 07:03:39', 'staff_id': 'A456', 'staff_name': 'James', 'staff_department': 'Graphic', 'service_id': '22222', 'service_number': 'XU-22211', 'State': 'AAA', 'City': 'AAA'}, {'log_number': '3', 'timestamp': '2020-01-27 14:29:11', 'temp_staff_id': 'A571', 'temp_staff_name': 'Mary', 'staff_department': 'Engr', 'service_id': '89000', 'service_number': 'SP-89001', 'State': 'BBB', 'City': 'BBB'}, {'log_number': '4', 'timestamp': '2020-01-27 15:08:20', 'staff_id': 'A765', 'staff_name': 'Alex', 'staff_department': 'Sales', 'service_id': '09880', 'service_number': 'XU-09880', 'description': 'This is description3333'}], 'total_hero_query': '13'}, 'response_time': '0.723494', 'transaction_id': '909122', 'transaction_status': 'OK', 'transaction_time': 'Fri Feb 28 15:27:51 2020'}}
'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I edit below

```
for row in json_in['response']['client_log']['data']:
```

The error related with the key gone but now error related to sql

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'description1, 2020-01-11 04:23:31, Krill, Sales, BU-11111, 1, 11111),(A123, This' at line 1
```

This error maybe due to different keys or non exists keys in the dictionary data as per my earlier problem of this thread... 
I really need help as till date...still not able to resolve the issue. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: instead of having a hard coded piece of sql, you need to add the keys of the dict and the corresponding values to the sql for each json entry.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of hardcoding the sql to have every column. You need to dynamically build the sql statements to have the columns/values that you DO have.

This can be done with a simple loop.

Also instead of immediately executing the insert command. I put them into a list so that you can then thread all the uploads to run at the same time. I did *not* write the thread portion of the code, so you will need to do that. The 2nd loop will need to be replaced with thread code, or if you aren't going to thread you can just do the execute instead of appending it to the `sql_inserts` variable.

## Edit: Added Json Loading.

So I don't exactly know how your data is coming into the code. But raw json data shows up as a unicode string. You have to format it into a dictionary. Luckily there is a handy dandy python module that does that.

So we can just import the json module and then load the data into it.

## Also note that I had a copy and paste error with a variable name.

Make sure any of the code that says `keys` now says `sql_keys`

```
import json

# This converts the json data into a python dictionary so that python can process it.
json_in = json.loads(mydata)

sql_template = 'INSERT INTO `table1` ({}) VALUES ({})'
sql_inserts = []

for row in json_in:
    sql_keys = row.keys()
    sql_values = []

    for key in sql_keys:
        sql_values.append(row[key])

    # This is the line my copy and paste error was on
    sql_inserts.append(sql_template.format(', '.join(sql_keys), ', '.join(sql_values)))

for insert in sql_inserts:
    cursor.executemany(insert, mydata['response']['client_log']['data'])
```

This is a very clean and easy to read way to do this. If you really cared about how many lines of code there are, like in a code golf situation, you could make this sorter by doing list comprehension and/or possibly a lambda.

Comment: Hi...thank you sir... json_in in the 1st for loop is my dictionary right in this case is mydata right? I replace json_in with mydata... I follow your exact code above and return error ''unicode' object has no attribute 'keys' ...Im not doing any thread...just to ensure the data can be inserted...so far data cannot be inserted.

Comment: So for your json object. Did you json decode it into python? Python doesn't natively handle json, but a json object is basically a python dictionary, so it can be decoded. If you don't know how I can edit the answer and show you.

Comment: There it's updated. Note the portion where I json load the variable ```mydata``` and then use json_in from then on.

Comment: Actually ... mydata is already in dictionary ...i have updated above how i read the json and load as a dictionary. I have replace accordingly as per my reply message and getting  error ''unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'...

Comment: Well all dictionaries have the keys method. That's built in to python. So that tells me that the data is *not* a dictionary. Have you put a breakpoint after you load the data into mydata and confirmed it's data type?

Comment: from mydata (print(type(mydata))) I'm getting dictionary data type --> <class 'dict'> ... I have tried re write the code...and still return the same error... I can confirm...the file is a valid json and return dictionary object. I also follow the step given above...confuse as it seems good line by line...but still not run properly...  I sharing full json file and updated above... can you help run with the json file. Thank you

Comment: After change .join(keys) to .join(sql_keys)... still return error but now error 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: I edit ' for row in json_in['response']['client_log']['data']: ' the error related with the key gone but now error related to sql ' 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'description1, 2020-01-11 04:23:31, Krill, Sales, BU-11111, 1, 11111),(A123, This' at line 1 '  --- i have updated above

Comment: Can you post the sql that your code, combined with mine, is now producing?

Comment: Hi sir, it exactly as per your code above sir. When I executed the code it return sql syntax error. The missing keys in each dict must be resolve 1st. Thus I need to check missing key and if got missing keys add the keys accordingly. I will update later and share with yo u sir.